# Increasing memory when using NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use NSURLConnection to make continuous post requests to a server.
But I've noticed that my memory is increasing and increasing, and it is not coming down, even after I stopped the continuous spam.
After a while the app will crash.

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong here, and how I can solve this problem?
I am using ARC here.

Thanks in advance

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1f target:self selector:@selector(continuousCall) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) continuousCall {
    NSString * json = @"{\"a\":{\"a1\":{\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"1\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"2\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}},\"a2\":{\"7\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"8\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"4\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"5\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"1\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"6\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"2\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}},\"a3\":{},\"a4\":{\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"1\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"2\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}}}}";

    [self connectWith:json];
    json = nil;
}

-(void) connectWith: (NSString*) json {
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //    [request addValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //#1
    //    NSURLConnection * urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    //#2
    NSURLConnection * urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [urlConnection start];

    //#3
    //    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    //    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    //        NSLog(@"%@", response.description);
    //        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    //    }];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    connection = nil;
    //    connection
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it has nothing to do with NSURLConnection, which I thought was casusing the problem.
I am using the JSONKit library and for some reason the memory of CFString keeps piling up. I am using NSJSONSerialization instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing something that creates a lot of temporary objects, you may wish to create a new [NSAutoreleasePool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) pool, like so:

```
-(void) continuousCall {
    id myPool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    NSString * json = @"{\"a\":{\"a1\":{\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"1\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"2\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}},\"a2\":{\"7\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"8\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"4\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"5\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"1\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"6\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"2\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}},\"a3\":{},\"a4\":{\"3\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"1\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72},\"2\":{\"value1\":255,\"value2\":234,\"value3\":0},\"0\":{\"value1\":0,\"value2\":255,\"value3\":72}}}}";

    [self connectWith:json];
    json = nil;

    // drain the new pool
    [myPool drain];
}
```